# Are there differences with setting up inbound ports on Docker vs Docker Desktop for Mac

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Docker Desktop is no longer allowed at my corporate job. Because I was having trouble setting up Docker on my company computer I developed the server on my personal laptop. My personal laptop was using Docker Desktop. When I finally setup my company computer with Docker the app is not working. I cannot access the inbound port of the server from Postman. I have no idea why it works on one computer and not the other. Are there any differences that must be addressed using Docker vs Docker Desktop?

`What I have tried`:

I have tried to Google to no avail.

***Dockerfile***:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9000

ENV MONGODB_USERNAME=admin
ENV MONGODB_PASSWORD=password

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: "mongo"
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    env_file:
      - ./env/mongo.env
  mockserver:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - "./src:/app/src"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    env_file:
      - ./env/server.env
volumes:
  data:
```

The instructions i used to install Docker on Mac are from the following webpage.

```
https://www.robinwieruch.de/docker-macos/
```

The url I am attempting to hit is

```
http://localhost:9000/api/software-source
```

The error I get in Postman is:

[image]

Probably doesn't matter but the route I am hitting is below, I am using a wildcard.

```
const apiRoutes = routes(client);

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

router.route('*')
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    const modelName = req.path.slice(1);

    client.db(SERVER)
      .collection(modelName)
      .find()
      .toArray()
      .then(response => {
        res.status(200).json({
          error: false,
          loading: true,
          response: {
            data: [...response]
          }
        });
      }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: error
        });
      }
    );
  }
)
```

Comment: If you were using Docker Desktop before, how are you running Docker in the new setup?  What URL are you trying to connect to, and what errors do you get?

Comment: I updated the question with the information you requested. Thanks you.

Comment: Also to eliminate Postman from the equation I ran the node app without Docker and the endpoint works as expected.

Comment: The setup you link to uses `docker-machine` to set up a Docker VM (a very reasonable approach, this is what basically everybody did before there was Docker Desktop).  Since it's in a separate VM, though, and doesn't have the fancy wiring Docker Desktop has, you need to use the `docker-machine ip` address to connect to containers, not `localhost`.

Comment: could be that you dont listen on the public network interface inside the container. Its a common mistake. Make sure you do something like listen 0.0.0.0:9000 from your node app. Instead of listen 127.0.0.1:9000.

Comment: Does this pertain to setting up node ports or something along that lines. Are there any links to more information about setting up the docker-machine ip address to connect to containers?